# How to handle large quantity of static assets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-hosting

I have a static react website hosted on `apache 2.4`. There is no database or serverside code. The website is powered by many relatively small data files (YAML if it matters) that hardly ever change, and are publicly hosted on the same web server.

Some pages on the site need to request many of these data files, upwards of 100-200. Is it expensive to request that many public files from the web server? By my understanding, if 10 different people happen to visit that page, the server will be spammed with 200 * 10 requests for data files.

I feel that creating a database for this content is overkill, considering it will almost never need to be updated. Should I just move all of the data into javascript files to bundle with the rest of the React code (bundle size would more than double)? Should I upload all of the data files to a CDN? Or is it cheap enough to request public files (I could implement pagination, for example only fetching 20 data files at once, although I still worry that this may bombard the server)? What is the best way to handle fetching many static assets?

Comment: Use a CDN and it'll cache all of your static resources and serve them. Cloudflare has a very nice free version.

Comment: If you're really concerned about performance, ditch Apache httpd and use [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com). If you're concerned about server bandwidth offload them all to a CDN or object-store like Amazon S3. How "expensive" are these requests? A client pulling down 10MB of data is pretty much inconsequential these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CDN to cache them remotely.

Then,
How about caching them in frontend in the initial call? No call at all after that.

You can use **indexedDB** or **LocalStorage**

It will drastically drop the requests.

Comment: CDN + IndexedDB cache sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.